# Can't get all tags from XML file

Tags: xml, linq

I am having problems with getting all the tags from my XML file that I have. In my XML file I have an option tag which contains descriptions.

```
<selection id="1">
    <desc>You see a cat stuck up in a tree, do you</desc>
    <option>
        <desc goto_id="2">Help the cat</desc>
        <desc goto_id="3">Leave the cat stuck in the tree</desc>
    </option>
</selection>
```

I have managed to get the Description and the ID from the selection, but when I try to create an array on the objects it only gets the first one when I loop through it.

```
var selectionQueryNew = from selection in xml.Root.Descendants("selection")
                        select new {
                            Desc = selection.Element("desc").Value,
                            Id = selection.Attribute("id").Value,
                            Options = selection.Elements("option")
                                .Select(option => new {
                                    Desc = option.Element("desc").Value
                                }).ToArray()
                        };
```

I am having problems with the .Select area I think, any ideas why it would only select the first description from the XML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're only seeing the first description is because of this part of your LINQ query:

```
Options = selection.Elements("option")
                   .Select(option => new {
                       Desc = option.Element("desc").Value
                    }).ToArray()
```

The code is saying get all the elements named "option" from the collection in `selection`, and then select a single element from the collection of elements named "option".  What you want to do is get the collection of "desc" elements under "option":

```
var selectionQueryNew = from selection in xml.Root.Descendants("selection")
                        select new
                        {
                            Desc = selection.Element("desc").Value,
                            Id = selection.Attribute("id").Value,
                            Options = selection.Element("option").Elements("desc")
                                      .Select(option => new
                                      {
                                          Desc = option.Value
                                      }).ToArray()
                         };
```

In the above code, a select is performed on the collection of elements returned from `selection.Element("option").Elements("desc"), which captures all the descriptions in the array.